# How to check if files are the same in Unix C?

Tags: c, file, unix

How to check if one file is the same (has the same content) as the other file using Unix C? I mean, when I cant use `fopen, fread, fclose` but just `open, read, close`? I'm interested in answers which shows how to do this ONLY in Unix C.

I wrote a program that copies one file to another but have no idea how to check if they're the same :/ :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *in_filename = "in.txt", *out_filename = "out.txt";
    int in_fd, out_fd, bytes_read, bytes_written;
    int buffsize = 512;
    char buffer[512];
    int success = 0;

    in_fd = open(in_filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (in_fd == -1)
        return -1;
    out_fd = open(out_filename, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (out_fd == -1)
        return -1;

    for(;;)
    {
        bytes_read = read(in_fd, buffer, buffsize);
        if (bytes_read > 0)
        {
            bytes_written = write(out_fd, buffer, bytes_read);
            if(bytes_written < 0)
                return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (bytes_read == 0)
            {
                if (close(in_fd) < 0)
                    return -1;
                if (close(out_fd) < 0)
                    return -1;
                success = 1;
                break;
            }
            else if (bytes_read == -1)
            {
                break;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    if(success)
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", "Success!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Heres what I tried:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *in_filename = "in.txt", *out_filename = "out.txt";
    int in_fd, out_fd, bytes_read_in, bytes_read_out;
    int buffsize = 512;
    char in_buffer[512], out_buffer[512];
    int the_same = 0;

    in_fd = open(in_filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (in_fd == -1)
        return -1;
    out_fd = open(out_filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (out_fd == -1)
        return -1;

    for(;;)
    {
        bytes_read_in = read(in_fd, in_buffer, buffsize);
        if (bytes_read_in > 0)
        {
            bytes_read_out = read(out_fd, out_buffer, buffsize);
            if(bytes_read_out > 0)
            {
                int i = 0;
                for(i=0; i<buffsize; i++)
                {
                    if(in_buffer[i] != out_buffer[i])
                        the_same = 0;
                }
                the_same = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (bytes_read_in == 0)
            {
                if (close(in_fd) < 0)
                    return -1;
                if (close(out_fd) < 0)
                    return -1;
                break;
            }
            else if (bytes_read_in == -1)
            {
                break;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    if(the_same)
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", "Files are the same!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

but it shows that files are the same, while theyre not :(

Comment: Have you tried something and stuck somewhere?

Comment: @Rohan: yup I wrote a program that copies one file to another but have no idea how to check if they're the same :/

Comment: Check files both have the same size, then open both files and compare them byte by byte.

Comment: The question is in context of what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: If you can only use `open`, `write` and `close`, just open both files and write `'\0'` into both. Now they're the same!

Comment: @KerrekSB: hahaha very funny ...

Comment: @Rohan: ok wait a second I need to find my code

Comment: how could you say that two books have the same content if you are not allowed to read?

Comment: Why can't you try doing a cksum on both files and compare?

Comment: @Rohan: please see my edit if you can :)

Comment: Also, unless you know they will always be the same, I'd check to make sure they have the same file size before doing anything else.   If they're not the same size, they're not the same contents.  It could save you a LOT of time in certain circumstances for virtually no cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to read two buffers in the same time. For instance (also, think to handle errors), without using C standard library at all:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

static int 
bufcmp(const void *p, const void *q, size_t n)
{
    const char *p1 = p;
    const char *p2 = q;

    while (n-- > 0) {
        if (*p1++ != *p2++)
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    int fd2 = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    int same = 1;

    for (;;) {
        char buf1[BUFFER_SIZE], buf2[BUFFER_SIZE];
        ssize_t n1 = read(fd1, buf1, BUFFER_SIZE);
        ssize_t n2 = read(fd2, buf2, BUFFER_SIZE);

        if (n1 < n2) {
            same = 0;
            break;
        } else if (n1 == 0) {
            break;
        } else if (bufcmp(buf1, buf2, n1) == 0) {
            same = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (same)
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Same content.\n", 14);

    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);    

    return 0;
}
```

**NB (Thanks to [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342)):** This code is not wholly right. Indeed, it is not an error if the number of bytes read returned by `read` is smaller than the number of bytes requested. However, to shorten this code, I didn't include this management.

Comment: This code is buggy: there is no guarantee that both calls to `read` will return all requested data at once. `read` can return less data than requested.

Comment: Please consider fixing the posted code in the case when two calls to `read` return different sizes for the same file, or at least mentioning the problem. Your answer is accepted, so future users will find it and refer to the code it contains.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with using *two* buffers, one for each file, reading the same number of bytes into each and then comparing the buffer contents with `memcmp`?

Comment: There is'nt a problem to use memcmp, it's C standard, but you can have a problem with big files to allocate enough memory.

Comment: The buffer can be as small as one byte. You just iterate reading a buffer full, compare, if equal read the next buffer full. Repeat until difference found or EOF.

Comment: @Katie You can write a memcmp in basically one line of C if you are not allowed to use the Standard C version. Any kernel is likely to have an equivalent function anyway.